# how to get interactions from the top klout scorers using datasift

Tags: klout

I need to retrieve the interactions from top klout scorers using datasift.

Ex:
CSDL: interaction.content contains "music" and klout.score > 50"

This is giving the interactions from users who has klout score more than 50,
But i need the top 10 or 20 interactions.

Comment: This might need more detail. What do you mean by top interactions? By what measure are they the top interactions?

Comment: Based on klout score.. i.e. the top interactions that have highest klout score..

Comment: So the 'interactions' themselves don't have a score associated to the interaction,  but to the @handle that posted it. So given 5 interactions by PersonX, the score attached would be the same. Generally, with Datasift you'd set up a listener wit the Klout augmentation turned on, export the results after your time is up, and sort in whatever export format you selected.